# JMeter parameterization with GraphQL query

Tags: jmeter, graphql

I am trying to parameterize a GraphQL query being sent as Body Data in JMeter, but not getting the correct response.

Here is the graphql:

> {"operationName":"VPercentageQuery","variables":{"thestate":"CA"},"query":"query VPercentageQuery($thestate: [String]) {\n  nodeQuery(filter: {conditions: [{operator: EQUAL, field: "type", value: "v_data"}, {operator: EQUAL, field: "field_vev_percentage_state", value: $thestate}]}, sort: {field: "field_year", direction: DESC}, limit: 3) {\n    entities {\n      entityLabel\n      ... on NodeVData {\n        fieldVevPercentageState\n        fieldStatePercentage\n        fieldEffectiveDateRange\n        fieldYear\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}

Now, substituting "CA" with "${state}"

> {"operationName":"VPercentageQuery","variables":{"thestate":"${state}"},"query":"query VPercentageQuery($thestate: [String]) {\n  nodeQuery(filter: {conditions: [{operator: EQUAL, field: "type", value: "v_data"}, {operator: EQUAL, field: "field_vev_percentage_state", value: $thestate}]}, sort: {field: "field_year", direction: DESC}, limit: 3) {\n    entities {\n      entityLabel\n      ... on NodeVData {\n        fieldVevPercentageState\n        fieldStatePercentage\n        fieldEffectiveDateRange\n        fieldYear\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}

Now, creating a state.csv file with just one column have entries:

CA
VA
SD
ND

and adding a CSV Data Set Config , Config Element

Not getting the response with states in the csv file

I am using JMeter 5.3

Answer (score 0):

`"variables": {"thestate": "${state}" }` works , add CSV Data Set Config
with Ignore First Line to True ( if you have a heading, `state` )
and just add all states in one column, plus keep the Loop Count in the